# in firebase realtime database delete post by timestamp

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

[It is my Realtime Database data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp4gv.png)

```
 "Posts" : {
"-MCCtOfEcs-t8OhKAj_R" : {
  "description" : "",
  "picture" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/instagram-c0686.appspot.com/o/blog_images%2Fimage%3A22222?alt=media&token=eb7ffc1f-f7bd-4ab7-a108-5baf92e3ef47",
  "postKey" : "-MCCtOfEcs-t8OhKAj_R",
  "timeStamp" : 1594739760019,
  "title" : "",
  "userId" : "1tXK0R5B9uOWyAbzlZMEIs6axHo1"
},
"-MCCtPZxoFEChRczT9nY" : {
  "description" : "",
  "picture" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/instagram-c0686.appspot.com/o/blog_images%2Fimage%3A22222?alt=media&token=c92b64ff-c2f6-4076-949a-b176253f0497",
  "postKey" : "-MCCtPZxoFEChRczT9nY",
  "timeStamp" : 1594739763718,
  "title" : "",
  "userId" : "1tXK0R5B9uOWyAbzlZMEIs6axHo1"
},
```

I want to delete a post by using the equalTo timeStamp variable. So I make a code.

```
Query fquery =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("timeStamp").equalTo("1615602220595");
```

But I don't know why not working.. when I do this

```
Query fquery =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("postKey").equalTo("-MCCtOfEcs-t8OhKAj_R");
```

It's worked.

Here is full code.

```
public class PostDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imgPost,imgUserPost,imgCurrentUser;
TextView txtPostDesc,txtPostDateName,txtPostTitle;
EditText editTextComment;
Button btnAddComment;
String PostKey;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
RecyclerView RvComment;
CommentAdapter commentAdapter;
List<Comment> listComment;
static String COMMENT_KEY = "Comment";
InputMethodManager imm;
EditText et;
Button btnDeletePost;
String myUid;
String UId;
String postImage;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;







@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_detail);
    imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.post_detail_comment);



    // let's set the statue bar to transparent


    // ini Views
    RvComment = findViewById(R.id.rv_comment);
    imgPost =findViewById(R.id.post_detail_img);
    imgUserPost = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_user_img);
    imgCurrentUser = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_currentuser_img);

    txtPostTitle = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_title);
    txtPostDesc = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_desc);
    txtPostDateName = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_date_name);

    editTextComment = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_comment);
    btnAddComment = findViewById(R.id.post_detail_add_comment_btn);
    btnDeletePost = findViewById(R.id.button_delete);


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    // add post delete button
    mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    myUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    btnDeletePost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //여기 수정 주의 UId.equals(myUid)
            if (true){
                Toast.makeText(PostDetailActivity.this,"삭제중...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                beginDelete();
                onBackPressed();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(PostDetailActivity.this,"다른 사용자의 게시글입니다.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    // add Comment button click listner

    btnAddComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            btnAddComment.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            DatabaseReference commentReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(COMMENT_KEY).child(PostKey).push();
            String comment_content = editTextComment.getText().toString();
            String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
            String uname = firebaseUser.getDisplayName();
            if (firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl()!=null){
                String uimg = firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                Comment comment = new Comment(comment_content,uid,uimg,uname);
                commentReference.setValue(comment).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        showMessage("comment added");
                        editTextComment.setText("");
                        btnAddComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        showMessage("fail to add comment : "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

            }
            else{
                String usphoto =Integer.toString(R.drawable.userphoto);
                Comment comment = new Comment(comment_content,uid,usphoto,uname);
                commentReference.setValue(comment).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        showMessage("comment added");
                        editTextComment.setText("");
                        btnAddComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        showMessage("fail to add comment : "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }




        }
    });


    // now we need to bind all data into those views
    // firt we need to get post data
    // we need to send post detail data to this activity first ...
    // now we can get post data



    // 게시글 사진 백지 케이스
    postImage = getIntent().getExtras().getString("postImage") ;
    if(postImage!=null){
        Glide.with(this).load(postImage).into(imgPost);
    }
    else{
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.whitepaper).into(imgPost);
    }


    String postTitle = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
    txtPostTitle.setText(postTitle);

    String userpostImage = getIntent().getExtras().getString("userPhoto");
    if (userpostImage!=null){
        Glide.with(this).load(userpostImage).into(imgUserPost);
    }
    else {
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.userphoto).into(imgUserPost);
    }

    String postDescription = getIntent().getExtras().getString("description");
    txtPostDesc.setText(postDescription);

    // set comment user image
    if (firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl()!=null){
        Glide.with(this).load(firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl()).into(imgCurrentUser);
    }
    else{
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.userphoto).into(imgCurrentUser);
    }
    // get post key
    PostKey = getIntent().getExtras().getString("postKey");

    String date = timestampToString(getIntent().getExtras().getLong("postDate"));
    txtPostDateName.setText(date);
    // get post uid
    UId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("userId");



    // ini Recyclerview Comment
    iniRvComment();


}

private void beginDelete() {

    StorageReference picRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(postImage);
    picRef.delete()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    //image deleted, now delete database
                    Query fquery =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("timeStamp").equalTo("1615602220595");
                    fquery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                ds.getRef().removeValue(); // remove values from firebase where postkey matches
                            }
                            //Deleted
                            Toast.makeText(PostDetailActivity.this,"게시글이 삭제되었습니다.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //failed, can't go further
                    Toast.makeText(PostDetailActivity.this,""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

}

public void linearOnClick(View v) {
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);
}


private void iniRvComment() {

    RvComment.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    DatabaseReference commentRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(COMMENT_KEY).child(PostKey);
    commentRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listComment = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot snap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Comment comment = snap.getValue(Comment.class);
                listComment.add(comment) ;

            }

            commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(getApplicationContext(),listComment);
            RvComment.setAdapter(commentAdapter);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });




}

private void showMessage(String message) {

    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


private String timestampToString(long time) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
    String date = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd",calendar).toString();
    return date;


}
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also indicate what is that `~~~`?

Comment: I edited json file and ~~~ thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the first node (`-MCCtOfEcs-t8OhKAj_R`) that exists in the "Posts" node, please note that there is **no** need to perform a query. Since the key of the node is the same as the value of the `postKey` field, then you should simply use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
db.child("Posts").child("-MCCtOfEcs-t8OhKAj_R")).removeValue();
```

I also recommend you attach a complete listener to the `removeValue()` operation, to see if something goes wrong. If you don't have the proper rules, then an Exception will be thrown.

**Edit:**

According to your last comment:

> I want to delete Instances that have old timestamp.

In this case, you indeed need to use a query. If you need to delete, for example, children that are before a specific timestamp, then you use the [Query#endAt()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#endAt(double,%20java.lang.String)) method, which:

> Creates a query constrained to only return child nodes with a value less than or equal to the given value, using the given orderBy directive or priority as default, and additionally only child nodes with a key less than or equal to the given key.

Here is a working example:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query queryByTimestamp = db.child("Posts").orderByChild("timeStamp").endAt(1615602220595);
queryByTimestamp.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                ds.getRef().removeValue();
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result of this query will be the removal of all children that exist before `1615602220595`.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But May I question about timestamp issue??

Comment: What about it ?

Comment: I want to delete Instances that have old timestamp. But my database structure is like that -> "Posts" : {
"postkey1" : {

  "timeStamp" : 99 ,

},
"postkey2" : {

  "timeStamp" : 100,

}, I can't approach to timeStamp because they have a parent part postkey1, postkey2 there are defferent. so I can't use orderbychild("timeStamp") to collect timeStamp instances.. Do you have idea about approach to timeStamp by ignoring postkeypart?

Comment: In that case, please check my updated answer. Is ok now?

Comment: Thank you very much!! but it is not working.. I add Toastmaketext is it working , but none of them including logcat message not show.